# How to stack cards horizontally for later viewing of carousel?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css, flexbox, twitter-bootstrap-4

Here's the goal: I want to create a card carousel where you click on arrows left and right to scroll through all cards.

My preferred way of doing this: Stacking `card-deck`s and transition to the next `card-deck` when an arrow is pressed. To clarify: you will only ever see one `card-deck` at a time, but I want them side to side to be able to css transition between them.

Right now I got

```
<row>
    <card-deck>
        <card/> x 3
    </card-deck>

    <card-deck>
        <card/> x 3
    </card-deck>

    <card-deck>
        <card/> x 3
    </card-deck>
</row>
```

which will obviously stack the card decks vertically because all `card-deck`s are full width (I'm using the flex option in bootstrap 4, so wrapping applies here). Now, how do I get them to be 100% wide but stack horizontally so that I can later hide the overflow and scroll through the decks?

I've tried all kinds of things, I don't really know how to go at this. Here's a fiddle to save you some time setting it up:

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7y6f8mjc/7/)

Also, if you know of an up-to-date alpha 4 bootstrap CDN with flex enabled, let me know. The one I'm using is a few days old.

Comment: Make each deck a carousel-item: http://www.codeply.com/go/WEbiqQvGhy

Comment: @Skelly wow, completely overlooked that possibility. Make a proper answer out of it and I'll accept immediately. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make each `card-deck` a carousel item and use Bootstrap's carousel() component..

```
<div class="carousel-inner">
       <div class="card-deck carousel-item">
             <div class="card">
                    ...
```

Working example: http://codeply.com/go/WEbiqQvGhy

[Update using Bootstrap 4 alpha 6](http://www.codeply.com/go/XrtNGqK2By)

Comment: note that if you're using the flex-box version of bootstrap, you'll have to use another wrapper around `card-deck` with the `carousel-item` class instead of just using them both on one div. Otherwise the `card-deck` css will be overridden (`display: block` most notably)